# How to convert data frame in r from positive to negative

Tags: r, dataframe, scalar

I would like to multiply my r dataframe with minus 1, in order to reverse the signs of all values (turn + to - and vice versa):

This does not work:

```
df_neg <- df*(-1)
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What is the output of `df_neg`?

Comment: Does your data frame have any non-numeric values? (e.g. strings or factors)

Comment: That code should work (even without the parentheses). What's the error?

Comment: it was indeed the non-numerics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is all numeric, the code you posted should work.  I'm going to assume you have some non-numeric values we need to work around

```
# make a fresh copy
df_neg <- df

# now only apply this to the numeric values
df_neg[sapply(df_neg, is.numeric)] <- df_neg[sapply(df_neg, is.numeric)] * -1
```

Comment: Looks like the right strategy to me. You can also save off `sel <- sapply(df_neg, is.numeric)` first so you don't have to type it all out twice. E.g.: `df_neg[sel] <- df_neg[sel] * -1`

Answer (score 10):

Here'a a tidyverse way to alter only the numeric columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df_neg <- df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(. * -1))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is working :

```
data$negative = data$positive*(-1)
```